# Using Google Maps API in Android application

Tags: android, google-maps

I was looking at the Google Map API for the first time and I had a quick question. I am woking on an Android application and I was wondering if there is a good way to take a route that I have created using Google Maps (snapping to roads) and use the API to display this route on an Android application?

I see that there is a way to generate images overlayed with polylines created with coordinates but it seems like it would be tought to create a polyline for something like a curved road.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was removed from the maps API, but you could implement it yourself or use a library like this one: http://home.ameliemedia.com/android-app-aroundme/#tips